# SpaCy v3 custom NER model training

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am trying to create a NLP project using spacy and python that extracts entities from text.

I need some custom entities so I created a JSON file with annotated articles that I am using to train my model with.

The issue I am facing is that instead of creating a new custom model, I want to add few entities to a pre existing model like "en_core_web_sm" but when I change my source for [components.ner] in my config file to "en_core_web_sm' I am getting only the new entities output. Its like the pre-trained model lost all its entities and is only using the new custom entities.

Note: This custom trained model is much more accurate than when I use the basic "eng" model but it just does not output the existing entities, just the new custom ones.

[image: custom trained model output]

[image: en_core_web_sm model output]

Please let me know how I could keep those pre-made entites in my new model.

here is the tutorial I used to create this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_7hJvl7P2A&t=685s

Comment: Spacy has a tutorial on how to combine multiple NER models: https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials/ner_double

Comment: @NickODell is there a way to combine them together in the config file and not the code?

Comment: Look at the config file in the directory that I linked.

Comment: @NickODell sorry to bother you again, here is my project repo https://github.com/Shakeeey/spacy_project 
can you please check what I am doing wrong since my double.cfg file is not creating a merged model